# Google map is not visible in jquery modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, jquery-ui-dialog

I wan't to display google map in jquery ui modal dialog. I open dialog but map is not visible. However it exists in there it just not visible.

This is page source:

```
<div class="dialog ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="photoLocation" style="padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: hidden; width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 390px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; " scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
    <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

It seams that z-index is wrong somehow but I have tried to change it on map div but that doesn't help.
When I open modal dialog this is code in there that should display map.

```
<script>
    var map;
    var styleArray = [
                      {
                          featureType: "all",
                          stylers: [
                          { visibility: "off" }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                          featureType: "road",
                          stylers: [
                          { visibility: "on" }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                          featureType: "administrative",
                          stylers: [
                          { visibility: "on" }
                        ]
                      }
                    ];

    (function () {
        window.onload = function() {
            var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('44.339565', '-114.960937');
            var options = { styles: styleArray,
                center: latlng,
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, options);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    icon: '../Content/Pointer.png',
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true
                });
        };
    })();
</script>
<div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

[image]
This is how I present modal dialog:

```
$(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("dialog")
                    .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                        close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        show: 'fade',
                        width: 460,
                        height: 390,
                        create: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("display", "none");

                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("padding", 0);
                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("border", 4);
                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-content").css("padding", 0);

                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-content").css("background", "#ffffff");
                            $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first").find(".ui-dialog-content").css("overflow", "hidden");

                        }

                    })
                    .load(this.href);
    });


@Html.ActionLink("Title", "Method", "Controller", new {imageId = @Model.ItemId}, new {data_dialog_id = "plid", @class = "openDialog button"})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mymodal">
    <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    var map;
    var elevator;
    var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng('44.339565', '-114.960937');
    var styleArray = [
        {featureType: "all", stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]},
        {featureType: "road", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }]},
        {featureType: "administrative", stylers: [{ visibility: "on" }]}
    ];
    var myOptions = {
        styles: styleArray,
        zoom: 6,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/walking-tour.png',
        draggable: true
    });

    $('#mymodal').dialog({width:335, height:355});
});​
```

[**An Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/524/).

Comment: Hi, I have added a picture that I get with this code. As you can see map div is there but I it seams it is hidden for some reason. In console I get this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. I also tried to add alert(..) in this function and it is not invoked.

Comment: May be you are making any mistake somewhere else, can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your current code.

Comment: Also what is the black area in the picture ?

Comment: I added code that I use to present modal dialog in question. Black area is modal dialog overlay.

Comment: What you are trying to do, where is `map`'s code in your added code ?

Comment: Html.ActionLink is asp mvc method to make a link and it point to a page Method. This code open a jquery modal dialog and load "Method" page in it. Inside that method page I have to display map.

Comment: Can you post the generated html by `@Html.ActionLink("Title", "Method", "Controller", new {imageId = @Model.ItemId}, new {data_dialog_id = "plid", @class = "openDialog button"})`

Comment: Whatever you do but you have to use map's code to get the map using javascript but you didn't use ?

Comment: Actually `load(this.href)` will load a page inside the `div` but you have to generate the map and then you can append the map inside the new div but for that you have to use an `id/class` for your new div.